# Sens de "Trans'pouët" / "trans'pe"

Tags: sens, néologismes

Bonjour,

J'ai trouvé ces phrases dans *Féerie I* :

> Ton âme de vache dans la **Trans'pouët** ! (p. 32)
>
> Ton âme de vache dans la **trans'pe** ! (p. 66 / 76 / 124)

D'après la note de la Pléiade, *Trans'pouët* est un autre avatar de *trempe*.

Tout de même, je n'arrive pas à comprendre le sens de *pouët* dans le premier cas et de *pe* dans le deuxième.

Savez-vous ce que les suffixes signifient ici ? Pensez-vous que les deux néologismes sont synonymes ?

Comment: Et pourquoi pas croire ce que dit la note de la  Pléiade? Je ne pense pas que nous soyons à même de faire mieux. Ce sont des reviseurs du plus haut niveau qui soit....en matière littéraire.

Comment: @Lambie Je ne mets pas en cause les capacités littéraires de l'éditeur de Céline dans la Pléiade, M. Henri Godard. Il me semble seulement que dans ce cas la note est incomplète.

Answer (score 1):

En regardant  le champ lexical environnant les occurrences de *Trans'pouët*  et *trans'pe*  on s'aperçoit de l'abondance du vocabulaire lié à la scatologie et à la mort :

- *je dois crever, je perds des peaux, des viandes des fesses, je fait plus caca, lavement, j'ai perdu cinquante kilos, s'ils en crevèrent de la pellagre*<sup>1</sup> ...

et viennent quelques vers libres qui contiennent :

> Ton âme de vache dans la trans'pe/ Trans'pouët

je ne peux que penser à **pet** : [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pet) « Fam. Gaz intestinal qui sort de l'anus avec bruit », et à **pouët** qui est une onomatopée pour décrire un bruit de klaxon, comme dit dans le [wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pouet#Nom_commun), mais aussi utilisée par les enfants pour décrire un bruit de .... pet (où il entre en concurrence avec prout). Quand on meurt, intestins et vessie se vident, avec les bruits qui vont avec.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>  Maladie dont les trois symptômes sont : une dermatite aiguë (« je perds des peaux »),  la diarrhée et des hallucinations qui peuvent conduire jusqu'à la mort.</sup>